# Pass data from dialog to activity Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have problem.
I made method which creates Dialog with my own layout. And I have no idea how to pass values (Strings) from my EdiText and asing to any variable in my Activity.
In comments you can see how I was trying to solve this.

Java method

```
public void makeDialog(){
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_ip);
        dialog.setTitle("IP connection");

// Todo passing value from dialog to activity
//        final EditText ipValueConnection = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipValueConnection);
//        ipValueConnection.setOnClickListener(this);
//        EditText portValueConnection = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.portValueConnection);
//        Toast.makeText(context, ipValueConnection.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Button dialogButtonLogin = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonLogin);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                tryToConnect();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });




        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
//        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.IP);

        dialog.show();

    }
```

XML layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/antena"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="#FFFFBB33"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ipValueConnection"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="IP" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/portValueConnection"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="PORT"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can make a HashMap of key - value pair and send it back.

Comment: but how to send it back?

Comment: You can make an `interface` and `onClick()` of button, you can pass the data.

Comment: I have onClick() of button, but it crashed when i make there Toast with values.

Comment: What is the logcat output?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Here you didn't got the reference of EditText that's why it gave error.

Comment: The way, you found the reference of Button on the same way make the reference of EditText's.

Answer (score 1):

Create a interface

```
public interface OnClickInterface {

    public void onClick();
}
```

call it instantiate it in your activity onCreate()

```
 OnClickInterface onClickInterface = new OnClickInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
               //Call Method from here
                requiredMethod();
            }
        };
```

//And in your dialog classs or method

```
public void makeDialog(OnClickInterface onClickInterface){
//Your code

 dialogButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             onClickInterface.onClick();


                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting means that a reference to the editText cannot be found in the current layout file. You have find the EditText in the custom dialog view instead of the activity view.

So instead of:

```
 final EditText ipValueConnection =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipValueConnection);
```

use:

```
 final EditText ipValueConnection =(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ipValueConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly,
your edit text is in dialog_ip so you need to use

```
final EditText ipValueConnection = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ipValueConnection);
```

Then you can get text from edit text as

```
String text= ipValueConnection.getText().toString;
```

And use that variable in your activity.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
 I have this kind of error if I do that

Comment: The error says that the edit text which you want is not in the view.. you can edit your commented section as in the answer above and then try running it..

Comment: I tried you code and I get the error you stated if I use `final EditText ipValueConnection = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipValueConnection);` which is in your code.. Try editing it as `final EditText ipValueConnection = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ipValueConnection);`